# Typescript interface keys from enum different types

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have list of properties that should be as a keys of interfaces with different types.
How better to implement them? I want not to allowed to use properties that not exist in enum.

```
export enum SomePropetries {
  prop1,
  prop2,
  prop3
};

export interface PropsInterface {
  [SomePropetries.prop1]: number;
  [SomePropetries.prop2]: boolean;
  [SomePropetries.prop3]: string;
}


// Usage example. 
// I have object of properties. Each of property can be updated separatelly.

let props: PropsInterface = {
   [SomePropetries.prop1]: null,
   [SomePropetries.prop2]: null,
   [SomePropetries.prop3]: null
};

const fieldToUpdate: {
  field: SomePropetries;
   value: number;
} = {
   field: SomePropetries.prop1,
   value: 123
};

props[fieldToUpdate.field] = fieldToUpdate.value;
```

Comment: please provide reproducible example, your exmaples contains a syntax errors

Comment: Please check. Now no syntax errors.

Comment: `let fieldToUpdate {` and `field: Properties = Properties.prop1,` is not valid syntax

Comment: Now I fixed a lot. Please check. I only have a n error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
But this is my problem

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to make `PropsInterface` all properties nullable.

```js
export enum SomePropetries {
  prop1,
  prop2,
  prop3
};

interface PropsBase {
  [SomePropetries.prop1]: number;
  [SomePropetries.prop2]: boolean;
  [SomePropetries.prop3]: string;
}

type NullableRecord<T> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] | null
}

type PropsInterface = NullableRecord<PropsBase>
```

Then, you are allowed to use `null` as a property type.

```js
let props: PropsInterface = {
  [SomePropetries.prop1]: null,
  [SomePropetries.prop2]: null,
  [SomePropetries.prop3]: null
}
```

This does not work,

```js
const fieldToUpdate = {
  field: SomePropetries.prop1,
  value: 123
}

props[fieldToUpdate.field] = fieldToUpdate.value;
```

because `fieldToUpdate.field` is infered as `enum`. I mean it expect all possible enum keys, whereas you are interested in only one `SomePropetries.prop1`.

Hence, in order to make it work, you should just use `as const` assertion.

```js
const fieldToUpdate = {
  field: SomePropetries.prop1,
  value: 123
} as const

props[fieldToUpdate.field] = fieldToUpdate.value;
```

Whole code:

```js
export enum SomePropetries {
  prop1,
  prop2,
  prop3
};

interface PropsBase {
  [SomePropetries.prop1]: number;
  [SomePropetries.prop2]: boolean;
  [SomePropetries.prop3]: string;
}

type NullableRecord<T> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] | null
}

type PropsInterface = NullableRecord<PropsBase>


// Usage exanple. 
// I have object of properties. Each of property can be updated separatelly.

let props: PropsInterface = {
  [SomePropetries.prop1]: null,
  [SomePropetries.prop2]: null,
  [SomePropetries.prop3]: null
};

const fieldToUpdate = {
  field: SomePropetries.prop1,
  value: 123
} as const

props[fieldToUpdate.field] = fieldToUpdate.value;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMoVcAClCMYGKAS2AGc4BvAKDjjALAEYAaex5gJg4acIBmWgF8A3LVqlEMYFABmAQwDGwOPkIUAQoopq6DANpYcGoiXIUAdANYBdAFxwUqAEZyJRk3mbEylGx5HOFcICAAbYEVETzhjbB9CP0tAoWCKC0QAcwkRSRgATyI4ADlkcPDFV0iAJWBlaAATAB4AFQA%20OABeGk5DMzhpOABrYAKIeThW4Nb%205js4AB9ncvDRfKK1MwoASRk5JVVu0tWq2vqm5u2dPXbJWgB6B7gAVQpFLLVQaLBIqzhHs8dnAABaKABuaggrgAVvV4BMuElYCk4ABRFQguCI2xyQpwZTREJqZBgRqKWSNOB6MCKKAU4AVApWSSReC2ChObZ7WQKFRqHoGOLeMzJAK2FjBFAVPjChKiizioJOaXhWXxUy%20RXWWyCKWrUQSWgNRAZODycjhRqtCAvMkM45Ci2MxpOEVa-w65jsTjgxThZDAJwsbjCERwXQEiCmmCSDmGZ1Wm128myKyJxoLHoZ5P2tN%20gPAMRAA)

Comment: Thank you! But how to make exact types?

Comment: What do you mean `exact`? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: I edited my example. Please have a look.

Comment: Now works good! Thank you so much. Here is some magic with nullableRecord. I have to learn about it ))